# How can I remote control a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, remote-control, remote-assistance

I'm looking for two ways to remote control the GUI of a Windows 10 computer.

First, I need a way to access a computer invisibly while someone is at the keyboard.  For example, someone says "hey, I need VLC installed" while using the computer, I'd like to be able to log in remotely without disturbing the user and install VLC, just as I can ssh or X2Go into a linux machine without bumping off the user at the console.  In the Linux world, this happens all the time.

Second, I need a way to help a user remotely by grabbing control of what they're doing, without the user initiating or responding.  Sometimes getting the user to initiate or even to accept an invitation for remote assistance is too hard. I worked at a university where we did this all the time on our Macs with ARD.

I'd prefer both of these things to work in such a way that:

- I can access Windows 10 machines
- I can remote in from macOS and Linux
- I can get in without opening another port in my firewall, such as by forwarding a port over ssh with the Linux server that I have at the remote site

Comment: Explain the downvote, please?

Comment: it's a privacy violation when you want to control a users computer without the user getting notified. In my opinion, this question sounds like "how can I make my life easier, while completely ignoring the principles of computer physics & privacy."

Comment: I read your question, as a question seeking software recomendation, which is not on topic here at Superuser.  Your only answer, so far, is a software recomendation, and not a very good one.  The single answer is right, you can install Teamviewer and while its not silent about the fact, you can use password prompt confirmation to avoid having to get the user to confirm the Teamviewer session.

Comment: @SimonS When you use ssh, do all of the other users get notified? Is that a privacy violation? To clarify, I'm not interested in secrecy, I'm interested in not logging off the user.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't categorize it as a software recommendation because I was hoping that this sort of thing was doable with RDP as is built into Windows. I'm not specifically asking for what piece of third-party software I should install. If that's the only solution, fine, but I'm not asking for that.

Comment: RDP will by definition log you out. It used to come with "remote help" but it does require the user to take some steps to get there. If you don't care that the user has to give concent, then there are some third-party programs available. Google is a big help too, as you are not the only person who ever needed this. In fact most IT companies rely on this, so there's plenty to find on the internet.

Comment: We used to have some similar software on the computers at my old school (I believe it was [this program](http://www.netsupportschool.com/monitor.asp)). Teachers were able to see the screens and take over our computer without any confirmation. I doubt this will work outside a domain and the ethics of installing this on someone's machine are also questionable. I don't think you can login remotely without either kicking someone off or them seeing you do it.

Comment: @LPChip The reason I'm asking here is that I didn't find anything with Google, and I'm surprised that I didn't find an answer very easily.

Comment: Expecting to be able to use a Windows feature, but connect to the Windows machines, from Linux and OSX is not realistic.  Which is the reason I categorized your question as a software recomendation.  How you remotely manage workstations is different from simply connecting to your machine remotely.

Comment: @aswine Seriously? This: https://www.google.nl/search?q=remote+control+software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=yG32V-WjJciRgAbr6prgDQ lead me to this: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/remote-access/tp/free-remote-access-software.htm

Comment: @Ramhound Using RDP from Linux and macOS is very realistic. I was hoping that there were some features of RDP or Windows that I didn't know about.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, seriously. Why would you expect me to find it if "What you're asking is not possible with most remote control software packages available."

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not possible with most remote control software packages available.

It is very bad practice to be able to control a pc without a users consent and users usually really dislike the idea of anyone being able to view their pc without their knowledge.

For that reason, most programs will have some form of protection against "taking over a pc, or notifying the user in one way or the other"

Now, given that Software recommendations is Off-topic here at SuperUser, I'm not going to tell you which options are available.

But you should know that there are IT-Corporate software available made to manage 1000 workstations at once. They collect information, send it to a general server, and through them, you can usually remote control and/or do things without the user knowing. For this to work, you need to install an agent first, but all is done through a website so managing works on most if not all Operating systems.

To get an idea, these are programs such as Kaseya, N-Able, etc. They cost a fortune too, but they are something you want to consider when you manage at least 500 pc's and need this kind of access. In any other case, the answer is simply: not possible.

Comment: I would throw in SCCM (System Center and Configuration Manager) as well if the purpose is only "install stuff".

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to be able to remotly control without opening firewall ports. By default remote control ports are closed for security matters. If you are planning this on environment with Active Directory, you can easily open ports with a GPO.

On Windows 10 you have some free ways to control a computer without the interrupting the user:

1. [Easy] - Using the console `compmgmt.msc` you can graphically do some configurations. The firewall exception GPO is the one at the beggining of this [guide](https://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/).
2. [Medium] - Powershell: deploying a GPO to enable remote powershell ([guide](https://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/)) you can run a remote session using `Enter-PSSession $computer`.
3. [Hard] - WMI: deploying a GPO to enable the WMI expcetion on firewall ([guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/84c78946-eb05-4068-877d-489153419d13/how-to-enable-the-wmi-entry-in-the-firewall-configuration-using-gpo-on-win7?forum=winserverGP)) and use the the `wmic` to access a remote node with the switch `/node:hostname`.

For taking over control, I really like DameWare. But it is expensive. If you are paying, LanSweeper is a nice tool for deployments and some actions.